# A local or parameter named 'student' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local param

Tags: c#

I have a `C#` program as below

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello MongoDb!");
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some Exception ", ex.Message);
        }
        }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        string con = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var client = new MongoClient(con);

        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("School", new MongoDatabaseSettings());
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("Students");
        using (IAsyncCursor<Student> cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter, options))
        {
            while (cursor.MoveNext())
            {
                IEnumerable<Student> students = cursor.Current;
                foreach (var student in students) //line#1
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        var student = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault(); //line#2
    }
}
```

Now what I know about C# variables & scopes is that the variable named `student` on line#1(see comments) is local & available only in the `foreach` scope.

while the variable student on line#2 is different & has a local scope of `MainAsync()` method.

Also C# don't have anything Hoisting like javascript so that on line#1 a variable with the same is already available.

Then why I am getting the below error.

> A local or parameter named 'student' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local param

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to reuse the variable name then simply declare it prior to using it (`Student student;`) and remove the `var` from later use (`foreach (student in students)`) and `student = collecti...`)

Comment: @Martin, agreed but that's not the intent of this post. the question is why so?

Comment: _I know about C# variables & scopes_ The scope includes the __whole block (method/class)__, not just the lines from the declaration onward. Think of GoTo !

Comment: It's by design, you can overcome restriction by creating 2 different code blocks (see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fYEiZv)), in which you can have local variables with same name. *Local function* would be harder to implement without this restriction: [which variable](https://dotnetfiddle.net/alhiwz) has to be captured?

Comment: Block scope is a language implementation detail, it doesn't exist at runtime.  Runtime scope is the method body.  That has practical implications, debugging would get quite hairy for example.

Answer (score 0):

> Then why I am getting the below error.
>
> A local or parameter named 'student' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local param

The reason why this happens is because of the way the compiler, translates your code in the background into the intermediate language that gets executed.

To better explain this lets create some simple examples.

```cs
int[] students = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

foreach (int student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

foreach (int student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

When we create this code the compiler can see that you're just re-using names, nothing wrong here, so when it goes to compile your code for you(to actually run it). It's going to do some optimization for you to help you out.

The compiler will generate something like this so it can keep track of the same named variable without it causing problems, and optimize it **so it doesn't have to create more objects than it needs.**

```cs
int[] students = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int student;

int length = students.Length; // this wouldn't be named length, it would have a randomly generated un-callable name that can't be referenced.

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    student = students[i];

    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    student = students[i];

    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

This is where we can see the problem of trying to create another object with **either** a different type with the same name, or the same type with the same name.

If we tried to create a similarly named variable with a different type the compiler wouldn't be able to create that variable at runtime because a variable had already been named and created with a different type.

Take this example, here we do the same thing as before, but then we use the same name later.

```cs
int[] students = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

foreach (int student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

foreach (int student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

int[] student = students[0..2];
```

The reason why(in a general sense) is because the compiler would run into an error when it tried to translate your code later on into this:

```cs
int[] students = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int student;

int length = students.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    student = students[i];

    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    student = students[i];

    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

// compiler can't create a variable with the same name again, 
// especially with a different type!!
int[] student = new int[2];

student[0] = students[0];
student[1] = students[1];
```

The same thing would happen if we try to create the same type and same name. The compiler would run into issues with polluting the method variables with the same name.

Let's look at what that might look like

```cs
int[] students = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int student = 12;

foreach (int student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

foreach (int student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

Would be translated into something like this:

```cs
int[] students = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int student;

// compiler can't create a second copy of student
int student = 12;

int length = students.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    student = students[i];

    Console.WriteLine(student);
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    student = students[i];

    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

**Editors Note**
The above is an over-generalization of an advanced topic, and the examples were written to best exemplify **why** this is happening, while also avoiding over-complicating the message meant to be conveyed by using real IL. The compiler doesn't normally generate IL anything looking like what I have provided.